# jQuery. Checkbox problem

Tags: jquery

See http://jsfiddle.net/kzaRh/
Click on `Renew` label, and checkbox will be selected. But if you click on `checkbox input`, then Renew label will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why using this way? That's the good practice:

```
<input id="autoRenew" type="checkbox" />
<label for="autoRenew">Renew</label>
```

No javascript required. Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzaRh/4/

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use a `<label for="autoRenew">Renew</label>`? If you do, it will automatically take care of checking/un-checking the associated box.